# nagiosgraph new services not showing

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios

I am using Nagios Core with Nagiosgraph and had only enabled graphing for cpu usage for a while. This worked fine, but now i wanted to add some more services (for example memory usage). The new services are not working (no rrd data is generated).
The Nagiosgraph site only says "no data available" and I get no error in apache log, nagiosgraph.log or nagiosgraph-cgi.log.

The new services are standard services (nsclient++ MEMUSE for example) and of course they are included in the map file. If I execute the checks manually, it shows also the perfdata.

I added the services by enabling the "graphed-service" use. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was a corrupt map file. It did not work for all services for some reason (even though there were mappings for them). However, replacing it and switching the server language to english worked. I had to do that, because perfdata returned values with commas like 5,32 instead of 5.32, so there was a perl error for conversion to float.